# Displaying dictionary values in View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using C# asp.net with MVC and I just started so I am having a little trouble understanding how to pass a dictionary to the view and print out each value.

My dictionary looks like:

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int>> values = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int>>();
```

What I would like is to have nested for each loops and print out:

```
firstInt   FirstString --valueInt
           SecondString--valueInt2
SecondInt  FirstString--valueInt3
           SecondString--valueInt4
```

etc.

Using C#, I would know how to do this as I would just go through the dictionaries and print out their values but I don't know how to do this in a view. The method that returns the dictionary is in the controller.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming Razor is your view engine, put the dictionary in the ViewBag and in your view, do something like:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.MyDictionary) {
<ul>
    <li>@item.Key
    <ul>
    @foreach (var subItem in item.Value) {
        <li>@subItem.Key --@subItem.Value</li>
    }
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
}
```